# How do I use the Firebase onAuthStateChange with the new React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-hooks

I am using `Firebase` to authenticate users for my application. I have created the `SignIn` and `SignUp` forms and can successfully create new users and sign in with stored users. However the issue comes with maintaining the user logged in state after a `Reload`.

The way I have seen it done in tutorials is to use a `HOC` like the following to check if the current user is logged in.

```
const withAuthentication = Component => {
  class WithAuthentication extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        authUser: null,
      };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.listener = this.props.firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(
        authUser => {
          authUser
            ? this.setState({ authUser })
            : this.setState({ authUser: null });
        },
      );
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      this.listener();
    }

    render() {
    return (
      <AuthUserContext.Provider value={this.state.authUser}>
        <Component {...this.props} />
      </AuthUserContext.Provider>
      );
    }
  }

  return withFirebase(WithAuthentication);
};

export default withAuthentication;
```

However I am looking to use the new `React` `Hooks` to remove the need for `HOCs`. I have already removed the `withFirebase()` `HOC` by using the `React Context` and `useContext(FirebaseContext)` to access a single instance of `Firebase`. Is there a way using the new `hooks` to mimic this `withAuthentication` `HOC` within `components` that I create?

I am using this tutorial

https://www.robinwieruch.de/complete-firebase-authentication-react-tutorial/

The section titled "Session Handling with Higher-Order Components" contains this part.

Thanks!

Comment: one option is to use the [react-firebase-hooks](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/csfrequency/react-firebase-hooks/#auth) library, which has support for `onAuthStateChange` through its `useAuthState` hook

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I did look into this, however I want to reduce the number of dependencies my project has as it will have minimal maintenance in future so I don't want to have to worry too much about breaking changes!

Comment: @TristanTrainer - did you figure this out? I'm struggling with the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59977856/firebase-listener-with-react-hooks

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can write a `Custom Hook` which registers an effect and returns the auth state

```
const useFirebaseAuthentication = (firebase) => {
    const [authUser, setAuthUser] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() =>{
       const unlisten = firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(
          authUser => {
            authUser
              ? setAuthUser(authUser)
              : setAuthUser(null);
          },
       );
       return () => {
           unlisten();
       }
    }, []);

    return authUser
}

export default useFirebaseAuthentication;
```

and in any `Component` you can use it like

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
   const firebase = useContext(FirebaseContext);
   const authUser = useFirebaseAuthentication(firebase);
   
   return (...)
}
```

`Index.jsx` will have this code in it

```
ReactDOM.render( 
   <FirebaseProvider> 
      <App /> 
   </FirebaseProvider>, 
   document.getElementById('root'));
```

This Firebase Provider is defined like this,

```
import Firebase from './firebase';

const FirebaseContext = createContext(); 
export const FirebaseProvider = (props) => ( 
   <FirebaseContext.Provider value={new Firebase()}> 
      {props.children} 
   </FirebaseContext.Provider> 
);
```

Comment: Beginner Question , am following the same tutorial . How did you write useContext(FirebaseContext) function .Can you please share the code if possible. Also how do you apply it if it is not similar to the provided in the tutorials . Thanks

Comment: @1nullpointer, useContext is a hook provided by react out of the box which you can use by importing like `import {useContext} from 'react';`

Comment: am trying to follow the tutorials but write the code with hooks . If am providing the context at the App level component , where do i use this code . Thats where my confusion began .  :
const firebase = useContext(FirebaseContext);
   const authUser = useFirebaseAuthentication(firebase);

Or should I wrap one into another .'Provide Firebase in React' Section in the tutorials specifically

Comment: @1nullpointer You will use useContext in components where you have `FirebaseContext.Consumer` in render of HOC.

Comment: Ok, that means I need not wrap the whole render return stmt like that   ? 

 <FirebaseContext.Consumer>
    {firebase => {
      return <div>I've access to Firebase and render something.</div>;
    }}
  </FirebaseContext.Consumer>

Comment: yes, you just need usecontext and that return you what the render prop of FirebaaseContext.Consumer returns in callback

Comment: am getting Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): _Firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__.default is not a constructor @  <FirebaseContext.Provider value={new firebase()}>

Am doing import firebase from 'firebase/app'

 firebase.initializeApp(config)
export default firebase

Comment: If I change it to <FirebaseContext.Provider value={firebase}> then i get firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged is not a function error

Comment: Never mind , got it working now by changing to firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged() and <FirebaseContext.Provider value={firebase}>

Comment: Question , can I merge below 2 lines so that i have a single line of code in all my consumer classes . Or does it vary based on context ?
const firebase = useContext(FirebaseContext);
   const authUser = useFirebaseAuthentication(firebase);

Comment: You can craete a custom hook that calls these two hooks and returns the result, much like you did for `useFirebaseAuthentication`

Comment: Thanks for this answer - it clarified a few things.
FWIW, I ended up one-lining the useEffect, like so:
`useEffect(() => firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(onChange), [])`

Comment: @ConorLuddy I think that might cause a memory leak because you are not closing the listener.

Comment: Does that mean when 'onAuthStateChanged' fires, MyComponent will rerender? (the value of authUser would update)

Comment: @Faris - my understanding is that useEffect will run whatever method it returns, which is the un-listen from onAuthStateChanged. Open to correction though...

Comment: @ConorLuddy yes, I think that is the case. 
Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri - I'm stuck with my efforts to implement your solution - do you have an advice for how to get past these config issues? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59977856/firebase-listener-with-react-hooks Thank you

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Why are you not using empty brackets as dependency? You don't want to setup a listener again if state changes? Setting a listener just once is enough.

Comment: @Badmaash Thank you for pointing it out. I missed it in my answer

Comment: thank you!!! really appreciate your answer